# Bootstrap banner overlapping existing element

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Hoping to get some help with a Bootstrap navbar.
When running the index file on my computer, the website is completely fine but when I upload it, it seems to lose the background image and the padding for the (Bootstrap) navbar overlaps on another navbar (CSS) that has a higher z-index.

I can't seem to figure out what's going on.

Link to the uploaded website:
https://anishrathod.com/photographyportfolio.html

The website index file run offline:
[image: run offline]

Comment: Try adding `position: relative` and `z:index: 100` in `TopNavbar` div

Comment: Questions should be useful for future readers. Instead of linking to an external site that will change in time, put the relevant code in the question.

Comment: position and z index have had no effect. I have resorted to changing both navigation bars to bootstrap bars so that they can work better together

Answer (score 0):

You can try `position: sticky;` on your `.navbar-fixed-top`, altough this reveals another top bar.

When you use `position: absolute` it will take out the element from the document flow. So other elements can you the space it would've been taken up.
So you would need some other way to preserve the space the navigation is taking up. (E.g. setting `padding` on the container, or something else).